# ASP.NET Backgroundworkers for spreadsheet creation: multiple ones interfering with each other?

Tags: asp.net, backgroundworker, export-to-excel

I am writing an ASP.NET application in which i need to create multiple excel reports. the report creation is pretty time-consuming (up to ten seconds for each) so i am using backgroundworkers to create them simultaneously.

My code looks a bit like this:

```
if (condition1)

{
excel_file_name = "TRANSFER";
BackgroundWorker worker_t = new BackgroundWorker();
worker_t.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
worker_t.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
worker_t.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
worker_t.RunWorkerCompleted +=
                       new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkerCompleted);
worker_t.RunWorkerAsync(excel_file_name);
}

if (Condition2)
{
excel_file_name = "NEFT";
BackgroundWorker worker_n = new BackgroundWorker();
worker_n.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
worker_n.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
worker_n.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
worker_n.RunWorkerCompleted +=
                       new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkerCompleted);
worker_n.RunWorkerAsync(excel_file_name);
}
```

there are more conditions but i haven't written them, since they are all similar. the only difference is the Excel_File_Name

the DoWork even then calls a class to create the excel files with the given name.

When condition1 and condition2 are both true, Here is the issue:
1. if i run this slowly using breakpoints during debugging, both files (TRANSFER and NEFT) are created.
2. if, however, i run it without breakpoints like a normal application, only the last file (NEFT in this example) is created.

What can be the issue?

Thanks

PS: For further information, here is the important code from the class that creates the excel file:

```
private static string placeDataInTemplate(string destFilePath, DataRow dr, bool isCoverLetter)
    {
        int loop = 0;
        ExcelNamespace.Application excelApplication = new ExcelNamespace.Application();

        ExcelNamespace.Workbook workbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(destFilePath, 0, false, 5,
          "", "", true, ExcelNamespace.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, true, false);
        ExcelNamespace.Worksheet workSheet = (ExcelNamespace.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[sheet_no];

        try
        {
            string value;
            string replicate;
            string replicate_end;

            // get data for Place Holders
            sDataTable dtPlaceHolderData = getPlaceHolderData(dr);

                           //make Display Alerts False
                excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;


            if (dtPlaceHolderData != null && dtPlaceHolderData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                int rowCntDt = 0; //Which row will be used for data?
                int i = 1;
                Excel.Range Find = (ExcelNamespace.Range)workSheet.Cells.Find("#",
                        (ExcelNamespace.Range)workSheet.Cells[1, 1],
                        Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
                        Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                        Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                        Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
                        false,
                        false,
                        Missing.Value);

                while (Find != null && loop <= 200)
                {
                    loop++;
                    value = Find.Value2.ToString();

                    if (condition)
                    //VERY long if...else if

                 }

                string approveDirPath = destFilePath.Replace(Path.GetFileName(destFilePath), string.Empty);
                workbook.Close(true, destFilePath, Type.Missing);
                excelApplication.Quit();
                string filepath = destFilePath.Split('-')[0];
                string approval_id = dr[0].ToString();
                return destFilePath;
            }
 return string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do something        
}
            finally
            {
                //release resources        
}
```

NOTE: I have removed a lot of needless code. I can paste it if needed. Thank you

Comment: Is `excel_file_name` used elsewhere? Instead of assigning to it, what happens if it is removed (so prevent any side-effects) and the literal (e.g. "NEFT") is directly passed to RunWorkerAsync?

Comment: I figured out the problem: I was passing the "excel_file_name" as a parameter to create the file name. But i was changing the same variable every time. What happened was, when i called the first backgroundworker, the "excel_file_name" was changed even before the worker was called.This resulted in calling of multiple workers with the same value for "excel_file_name". Right now, I am using multiple "DoWork" events with explicitly defined file names in each, instead of passing the name. I will look for an alternate solution to this. thanks

Comment: PS: Thanks pst, for your answer. You are bang on target. too bad I didn't read your answer before spending so much time figuring this out :)

EDIT: do you know of any other way i can pass the excel_file_name to the RunWorkerAsync? the file name is actually a part of a Datarow which also needs to be passed. the original code is
dr[5] = name;
and DoWork accepts only one parameter as far as i know

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause is some shared state between two threads - shared state may include excel application and workbooks. So you need to inspect your code for the same.

On the side note, instead of using Excel Automation to generate excel files, you may consider using some in-process library which would be perhaps more scalable and void of such issues. Have a look at one such [free basic library at code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/biffcsharp.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer VinayC :) I just figured out what the problem was, however, and I am posting that as an answer to this question in case otehrs had this difficulty